# Gradle Project Dependencies with Buildship

Tags: gradle-eclipse, buildship

I have successfully imported my project (used to be maven) into buildship.  If I run my build from the command line it all works.

What I am having issues with now - is that within eclipse the dependencies are not managed correctly.  All my projects are showing red "x"s since it can't determine the needed files from other projects and/or supporting jars.

I have tried right click, gradle, refresh project -> but that didn't help.  The build path shows no dependencies, and no jars (it shows an empty Maven library).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Gradle Dependecies (projects):
[image]

Gradle Dependencies (jars) [two different files, but same issue]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuepG.png)

Eclipse Buildship

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the project you are trying to import already contains a .project file, in which case Buildship will use the dependencies configured in that Eclipse .project file.

I suggest you remove any Eclipse .project files from the Gradle project and then do a fresh import.

Note that as of Buildship 1.0.9, you will see a dialog during the import that will allow you to decide whether to do a clean import or whether to take the dependencies from the existing Eclipse project file.